# Id selector not working in jquery when my html body is in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have body of the html inside php tags and i want onclick() to work but i want jquery to handle it. I tried to select the id and then use .on() method of jquery but it doesn't seem to work

So here's my php code

```
<body>
<?php
$home=  
    "<div class='heading'  >
        <p><b>blah blah blah</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-wrap'>
        <nav class='menu'>
            <ul class='clearfix'>
                <li><a href='./member.php'>$username's Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a >States <span class='arrow'>&#9660;</span></a>

                    <ul class='sub-menu'>
                        <li><a onclick='changeAllStatesToFalse();'>ALL APPLIANCES OFF</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick='changeAllStatesToTrue();'>ALL APPLIANCES ON</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick='getStates();'>GET STATES</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='./security.php?userid=$username'>Security</a></li>
                <li><a >About me</a></li>
                <li><a href='./logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!3 Toggle Buttons start>
        <div class='buttonsArea'>
            <div class='display'>
                 <label class='label toggle'>
                      App-1
                     <input type='checkbox' class='toggle_input' id='button1' onclick='updateTable(1);'/>
                     <div class='toggle-control'></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
            <div class='display'>
                 <label class='label toggle'>
                      App-2
                     <input type='checkbox' class='toggle_input' id='button2' onclick='updateTable(2);'/>
                     <div class='toggle-control'></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
            <div class='display'>
                 <label class='label toggle'>
                      App-3
                     <input type='checkbox' class='toggle_input' id='button3' onclick='updateTable(3);' />
                     <div class='toggle-control'></div>
                 </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!3 Toggle Buttons end>";


    if($username && $userid){

        echo "$home";
        if($errormsg)
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
    }
    else{
        header('Location:http://'.$raspiIp.'/EHDLOGIN_rpi/login.php');
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please Login');</script>";
    }



    ?>
</body>
```

And this is what i want alert when clicked on button with id:button1

So i am doing:

```
$("#button1").on("click",function(){

alert(1);

});
```

But this is not giving me any alert.
Plz help

Comment: you're dumping raw php text into a JS context. if `$errormsg` contains **ANY** js string metachars (e.g. `'`), then you're introducing a JS syntax error and killing the entire script block. always output via json_encode() - never dump raw text. And your `header()` call is pointless - all you're doing is producing is "headers already sent" errors.

Comment: And is `<!3 Toggle Buttons start>` supposed to be an HTML comment?  If so, it needs to be `<!-- Toggle Buttons start -->`.

Comment: It is better to split ths functionality and use 2 templates for login and home. Then in php you could just include different files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the elements dynamically so you need to register the event in the DOM so that as soon as the element is available, register the click event handler.

```
$(document).on('click','#button1',function()
{
    alert();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j6um1sq2/2/

Comment: Perfect. Glad to help.